# Why is R saying "argument is of length zero" and how can I fix this?

Tags: r, function, debugging, error-handling, arguments

R will plot the Venn diagrams and shaded areas correctly, but it will not say A or A' in the console. The image below is an example of what I'm trying to have done. Note that the function "venn" is used from the "venn" package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/venn/venn.pdf

[Example of preferred output in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNy0E.png)

```
genvd = function(x){
  x = venn(x,zcolor = "blue",ilabels = F)
  
  if (x == "A") {
    print("A",quote = FALSE)
    return(x)
  }
  else if (x == "~A") {
    print("A'",quote = FALSE)
    return(x)
  }
}

genvd("A")
genvd("~A")
```

Error Code:

```
Error in if (x == "A") { : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: I get a different error.  Can you show a reproducible example.  Also, specify the packages used i.e. for `venn`

Comment: @akrun the package used is called "venn."  
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/venn/venn.pdf
What error are you getting?

Comment: Please specify in your post because there are other packages having the same function `venn`.  I used a different package

Comment: okay I will do that

Comment: Note that `print` doesn't have any return value, so you cannot assign it to `set=..`

Comment: I fixed that and still get the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the usage of condition on the `venn` object instead of the original input.  We could assign it to a new object. In addition, `print` doesn't have any return value.

```
genvd <- function(x){
  
  venn::venn(x,zcolor = "blue",ilabels = FALSE)
  
  if (x == "A") {
    print("A",quote = FALSE)
    
  }
  else if (x == "~A") {
     print("A'",quote = FALSE)
    
  }
}
```

---

The `venn` object is not returning anything

```
> tmp <- venn("A", zcolor = "blue", ilabels = FALSE)
> str(tmp)
 NULL
```

-testing

```
> genvd("A")
[1] A
> genvd("~A")
[1] A'
```

Comment: Thank you. However, why does it say NULL underneath?

Comment: @kyle because it is just printing the plot and there is no return value (as in the update)

Comment: Is there a way to make it not say "NULL"?

Comment: @kyle then you don't need to assign it to anything.  i.e. just `print(venn(x, zcolor = "blue", ilabels = FALSE))` and `return(x)`

Comment: thank you for that. How do I make it not print out the "A" or "~A" ? I just need it to say A or A'

Comment: @kyle then, you don't need any `return`.  Updated the post